# How to resolve Object Manager has been closed error?

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

I'll appreciate if someone can point me to a tutorial or best practice on how to close
JDO connection. 
I constantly get `javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Object Manager has been closed` error whenever I include the finally block.
My code is below:

```
public static List<AgentEntity> findAgentEntityByString(String id) {
    List<AgentEntity> agententity = new ArrayList<AgentEntity>();
    if (id == null) {
      return null;
    }
    try {
        Query q = pm.newQuery("select id from " + AgentEntity.class.getName());
        agententity = (List<AgentEntity>) q.execute();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        log.warning(ex.getMessage());
    }
        return agententity;
  }
```

Regards

Comment: Perhaps address what happens in "finally" (I don't see it in your example). Maybe things are being detached?, or are you accessing things after close of the PM?

Comment: If I include the finally block, I get the persistence manager has been closed error. So I removed it outrightly. When I did that, code works well, but the log still complains that "persistence manager has been closed". With this, I couldn't retrieve the data stored in my ModelAttribute on the Spring Controller GET request to be displayed.

Comment: But you still haven't said what is happening in "close" of the PM, or what code is in your "finally block". The log tells you what happens, but we don't see it

Comment: As it is in finally @DataNucleaus, `finally { pm.close();}`

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution to avoid this *lazy loading* problem is to use the `size()` method forcing the `PersistenceManager` object to load the result list from datastore before being closed.

```
public static List<AgentEntity> findAgentEntityByString(String id) {
    List<AgentEntity> agententity = new ArrayList<AgentEntity>();
    if (id == null) {
      return null;
    }
    try {
        Query q = pm.newQuery("select id from " + AgentEntity.class.getName());
        agententity = (List<AgentEntity>) q.execute();
        agententity.size()  //Should populate the returned list
        return agententity;
    } finally {
      pm.close();
    }        
  }
```

Reference [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/46ef564317d1e17b).

Comment: Using the above code, I got the following `Object Manager has been closed

Caused by:

javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Object Manager has been closed
 at org.datanucleus.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:375)
 at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.close(JDOPersistenceManager.java:281)
 at org.opevel.server.dao.AgentEntityDAOImpl.findAgentEntityByString(AgentEntityDAOImpl.java:95)
 at org.opevel.web.AgentController.handleRequest(AgentController.java:80)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAcc`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to close your PersistenceManager here ?
If you want to close the Query you should use either 
`javax.jdo.Query.closeAll()` or `javax.jdo.Query.close(Object result)`.
So you can do either a transient copy of the result and than close the query and its result:

```
public static List<AgentEntity> findAgentEntityByString(String id) {
  if (id == null) {
    return null;
  }
  Query q = null;
  try {
      q = pm.newQuery("select id from " + AgentEntity.class.getName());
      return new ArrayList<AgentEntity>((List<AgentEntity>) q.execute());
  } finally {
    if(q!= null){
        q.closeAll();
    }
  }        
}
```

or you can close the result later explicitly:

```
public static List<AgentEntity> findAgentEntityByString(String id) {
  if (id == null) {
    return null;
  }
  Query q = pm.newQuery("select id from " + AgentEntity.class.getName());
  return (List<AgentEntity>) q.execute();
  }        
}
....
List agents = X.findAgentEntityByString("Foobar");
....
pm.close(agents);
```

Comment: I am calling the DAO method findAgentEntityByString() from a Spring Controller GET request, With this example, it means I'll have to close the result on the Spring side right?

Comment: I tried the above code, still no luck. Below is the error stack: `Persistence Manager has been closed

Caused by:

javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: Persistence Manager has been closed
 at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.assertIsOpen(JDOPersistenceManager.java:2125)
 at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.newQuery(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1247)
 at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.newQuery(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1234)
 at org.opevel.server.dao.AgentEntityDAOImpl.findAgentEntityByString(AgentEntityDAOImpl.java:107)
 at org.opevel.web.AgentController.handleRequest(`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the fetch plan just after getting the PM, then setting it to all before you perform your query:

import javax.jdo.FetchPlan;

```
    pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    FetchPlan fp = pm.getFetchPlan();
    fp.setGroup(FetchPlan.ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what fixed this for me is answered here:

[Why do I get "Persistence Manager has been closed" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016052/why-do-i-get-persistence-manager-has-been-closed-exception)

I had an instance reference to the persistence manager, I just made a local instance and all my errors fixed